# Add class to child element if class exist only in parent container

Tags: jquery

Im trying to add a class to an element if another element has class- in this case I want to give `.addinfo.col7` a class of `outofstock` when the class `.orderitem` exists. This Is what I got so far:

```
if ($(".stockinfo.col4").hasClass("orderitem")) {
    $(".stockinfo.col7").addClass("outofstock");
}
```

The problem is that I have several groups with the same classes - and this gives the class to all of them even though the child don´t have this class. How do I run this so its only executes on the parent container?

```
<div class="itembox centerbox col span_1_of_3">
    <div class="stockinfo col4 orderitem">
        <strong>Stock</strong>
        : 4
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="addinfo col7">
        <input type="button" id="pl237792buy" class="actionbutton" value="Köp" onclick="buy(this, 237792, null, 'pl237792qty', null, '/ajax/buy')">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next()` method like following.

```
$(".stockinfo.col4.orderitem").next(".addinfo.col7").addClass("outofstock")
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(".stockinfo.col4.orderitem").nextAll(".addinfo.col7").addClass("outofstock")
```

Comment: Hi! I just realized that in some groups there is another elment in between - so next doesn´t work for all groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like below:

```
$(".stockinfo.col4.orderitem").parent().find(".addinfo.col7").addClass("outofstock");
```

Answer (score 0):

`orderitem` is not the parent of the `stockinfo` div. Its a sibling, you can use `.siblings()` method for that

```
if ($(".stockinfo.col4").siblings(".orderitem").length) {
  $(".stockinfo.col7").addClass("outofstock");
}
```